# IOS willCacheResponse in connection delegate

Tags: ios, caching, nsurlconnection, restkit-0.20, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I would like to know which method is the validation part that will identify the cache-control header in response and that will call `connection:willCacheResponse:` delegate.

Because here I have customized the response header and expected `NSURLConnection` to call `connection:willCacheResponse:` but that is not happening.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection __unused *)connection
```

didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpresponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
NSLog(@"headers : %@", [httpresponse allHeaderFields]);
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[mutableDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:[httpresponse allHeaderFields]];
[mutableDictionary setObject:@"public, must-revalidate, max-age=300000" forKey:@"Cache-Control"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [connection currentRequest];

NSInteger statusCode = 200;
//id headerFields = nil;
NSURL *urlString = urlRequest.URL;
NSString* HTTPVersion = nil;
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"initWithURL:statusCode:HTTPVersion:headerFields:");
NSMethodSignature *signature = [self methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
[inv setTarget:httpresponse];
[inv setSelector:selector];
[inv setArgument:&urlString atIndex:2];
[inv setArgument:&statusCode atIndex:3];
[inv setArgument:&mutableDictionary atIndex:5];
[inv setArgument:&HTTPVersion atIndex:4];
[inv invoke];    

NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)self.response;
int code = [httpResponse statusCode];
NSLog(@"response status code : %d", code);
if ([self.response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [httpResponse allHeaderFields];
    NSLog(@"Header Discription:%@", [dictionary description]);
}

[self.outputStream open];
```

}

Comment: Show code examples. If you're using `NSURLConnection`, what does this have to do with RestKit? What and where is your delegate defined / connected?

Comment: Thing is that restkit has removed their caching implementation in newer version 20.0. Here based on this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restkit/Va8sPGF7MyE I got a idea like adding the cache-control header in response object so that restkit will take care of response caching.

Comment: The cache management is now done by `AFNetworking`, it uses the standard `NSURLCache` stuff but it doesn't use `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: Then how to proceed with my present implementation. Is my idea was wrong ?

Comment: Your idea should be correct, but you'd need to give more details of how you're setting the headers and how you're testing whether it's working or not. Are you checking what messages are actually sent to the server?

Comment: Here am not modifying anything in response and its header I was simply APPENDING the cache-control header in response header in connection didreceiceResponse delegate in AFConnectionOperation Class.

Comment: here is my response header -     "Cache-Control" = "public, must-revalidate, max-age=300000";
    "Content-Length" = 1868;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1";
    Date = "Mon, 08 Jul 2013 15:40:26 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
    "Set-Cookie" = "JSESSIONID=HOIJposjayUGr5nfhsXj8Q**.p_ws-ext4; Domain=services.walgreens.com; Path=/";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "X-ATG-Version" = "version=QVRHUGxhdGZvcm0vOS40";

Comment: @nik, I don't understand: you are saying you are not modifying the response; but then you say you "simply appending the cache-control header in the response headers `connection:didReceiveResponse:`". Not sure what you mean by this. The parameter _response_ in `connection:didReceiveResponse: ` is *immutable* anyway.  Please show your code ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Please check my edited question by doing like wise we can make NSURLResponse as mutable.

Comment: The code looks hairy. Not sure whether this means good or bad :) Anyway, if THIS works you certainly depend on internal implementation details of `NSURLConnection`. Perhaps it would be helpful, if you would explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: This was my sample code.. Here I trying to achieve a caching mechanism which should be configuration based for both GET and POST request. During compile time we should have a option like mentioning which request's response should cached and what should be its cachtimeout. I achieved this config based caching implementation in restkit 10.0 but restkit have removed all their existing caching technics in their newer version. So I was trying to achieve the same thing using server side caching technic. I hope you will now understand clearly. :)

Comment: Can't you implement the delegate method `connection:willCacheResponse:` where you return a new response with your desired attributes which is used for caching? That's the supposed way to address this problem. This implies, that the server sends a response including cache control headers.

Comment: BTW, *usually* a POST method cannot be cached. Only idempotent methods like GET, though the details are more complex (see RFC 2616 for "cacheable response).

Comment: FYI.. My question here I have successfully added cache-control header in response header which received from server but the delegate method willcacheresponse is doesnt get called. This is my query here.

Comment: I suspect your approach to modify the response headers does not work with NSURLConnection. According the documentation, the response is immutable.

Comment: YES I saw that and is there anyway to make call to that willCacheResponse method ? I thought customising the response header will automatically call that delegate method but it doesn't.

Comment: Basically there should be a validation part in core side to check for cache-control header in response will that validator method will call this willcacheresponse delegate I trying to make it restructure.